# switching orientation of flex container

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, flexbox

In a wordpress template I generate the following html:

```
<article class="home-post-container">
    <div class="home-post-thumb">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
            the_post_thumbnail(); 
        } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="home-post-content">
        <h4 class="post-title">
           <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h4>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</article>
```

I want to use a flex container to cause the `.home-post-content` to be beside the `.home-post-thumbnail` on the desktop, and below the thumbnail on smaller screens.

I've created the following CSS but the orientation isn't switching when it should (ie at 400px).

The rendered page is always `flex-direction: row` regardless of the screen width.

```
.home-post-thumb{
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
}
.home-post-content{
    flex:3 ;
}
@media (min-width: 401px;){}
    .home-post-container{
        display:flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
        flex-direction: row;
        padding: 1vw 1vw;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px;){
    .home-post-container{
        display:flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column; 
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1vw 1vw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is invalid. Rules inside `@media` query do not need a closing semicolon `;` and having them will break the query.

Also you opened a media query and closed it at the same line `@emdia (condition){}` thus making it obsolete.

The correct code would be like this:

```css
.home-post-container { border:1px solid; padding: 1em; }

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .home-post-container {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .home-post-content { flex: 1; padding: 1em; }
}
```

```html
<article class="home-post-container">
  <div class="home-post-thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="home-post-content">
    <h4 class="post-title">title</h4>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/4copxqdj/

P.S try to provide generated HTML instead of WordPress PHP code next time.

Comment: The syntax errors are the real reason for the error - the simplification is just gravy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS can be simplified. It also contained a few syntax errors.

```css
.home-post-container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1vw;
}
.home-post-thumb {
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.home-post-content {
    flex:3;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .home-post-container { flex-direction: column; }
}
```

```html
<article class="home-post-container">
    <div class="home-post-thumb">POST THUMBNAIL</div>
    <div class="home-post-content">
        <h4 class="post-title">POST TITLE</h4>
        POST CONTENT
    </div>
</article>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efpswpu2/1/)